# List all names from a table where the values on a third one are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have three tables, one with a client name and code, one with client code(foreign key) and rental number and the third one with the  return date and rental number(foreign key).

[image: The tables in question]

I need to list all client names where the return date is null and i'm completely stumped, i got 2 joins deep and deleted everything i had done because i realized some serious spaghetti was being cooked, can i get any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select clientname from client c inner join item i on c.clientcode = i.clientcode inner join itemrental ir on i.rentalnumber = or.rentalnumber where it.returndate is null
```

Maybe you used = null instead of is null

Comment: Man, guess what? Happened to me too and l learned the hard way :-)